# Chart From Two List in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have two list in sharepoint from which I have to select the X axis and Y axis with the drop down appropriately so that chart has to be displayed below.

Do help me out people

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use this webpart.

http://spjsblog.com/2012/02/03/spjs-charts-for-sharepoint-v3-x/

Comment: the moderator comment is usless on this post, some of the answers are just links to codeplex projects, blog post with the proper answer, etc. We wont copy paste their answer here.

Answer (score 0):

There are some charts on codeplex:
[Chartpart](https://chartpart.codeplex.com/), [Fusion charts](http://charts4sharepoint.codeplex.com/)